# hide UIViewController in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I have a home page with table and one button, with pressing my button I will load the qrCode reader view, I want to hide my qrCode view after scan the barcode,

would you please give me some hint what is the best way to do this? NSNOtification or ...
and how?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my qr view code that scans the code:

```
 - (void) readerView:(ZBarReaderView *)readerView didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet *)symbols 
fromImage:(UIImage *)image
{

ZBarSymbol * s = nil;
for (s in symbols)
{

    image_view.image = image;
```

// here I will go to httpReq class for addStamp method

```
    [[HttpReq sharedHttp] setCode:s.data];
    [[HttpReq sharedHttp] addStamp];

}
}
```

Here is my addStamp method that I have to hide the view in this method:

```
-(void) addStamp
{

// My code was here for connect to api



     NSError *jsonError;
     NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&jsonError];

     if(jsonError != nil)
     {
         return;
     }
 // I want to do it here when I have a success or not      

     BOOL success =  [[dic objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];

     if(success){

         [self addStampInDB:[[dic objectForKey:@"cardId"] intValue]];

     }else{

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[dic 
 objectForKey:@"error"]
                                                        delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil 
 waitUntilDone:NO];
     }

 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiding a view in Objective-C is quite simple:

```
[theView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: I have no visible interface for '' declares the selector setHidden I declared my view in .h file but

Comment: what does " mean? replace theView with whatever the view is called.

Comment: I know, "myView" but problem that i said

Comment: @adam self.view setHidden:YES

Answer (score 0):

When the addStamp method is called you could invoke a method that is defined in the first class using `performSelector` or you could follow protocol and delegate mechanism to keep it neat.